# jquery hover precedence and clearTimeout issues

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, cleartimeout

So I'm trying to make a dropdown for the cart on my website, http://www.beautracare.com/ , and so far if I mouse over the cart you get a dropdown fade in, but after a while it times out and fades out even if you're still moused over the cart dropdown. I tried creating a setTimeout and clear it when mousing over the dropdown, but it doesn't respond. I also tried playing around with the dropdown hover function in Jquery but it doesn't seem like its even triggering. Please help, thanks. The jQuery code is given below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    //get all link with class panel
    $('a.panel').click(function () {

                //reset and highlight the clicked link
        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //grab the current item, to be used in resize function
        current = $(this);

                //scroll it to the destination
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

                //cancel the link default behavior
        return false;
    });

    $('.wsite-nav-cart').hover(
        function() {
            if ($("#wsite-mini-cart").css("display") == 'none'){
                $("#wsite-mini-cart").fadeIn();
                timer = window.setTimeout(function() {$("#wsite-mini-cart").fadeOut(); }, 1500);
            }
        }, function() {
        }
    );

    $("#wsite-mini-cart").hover(
        function() {
             if (timer) {
                window.clearTimeout(timer);
            } 
            $("#wsite-mini-cart").css({'display':'block','opacity':1});
        }, function() {
            timer = window.setTimeout(function() {$("#wsite-mini-cart").fadeOut(); }, 1500);
        }
    );


    $('.wsite-nav-cart').click(function () {
        if ( $(this).attr("id")){
            $("#wsite-mini-cart").fadeOut();
            $(this).removeAttr('id');
        } else {
            $("#wsite-mini-cart").fadeIn();
            $(this).attr('id', 'active');
        }
        //cancel the link default behavior
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stWUP/) to show how I would solve this. If you mouseover the button, the cart shows up. If you mouseout the button, the cart hides. But if you move over to the cart, it stays visible, until you move out from it.

Basically, the `hideCart` is delayed with 500ms. If any bound element receives a mouseover during this time, it cancels the timer.

The code:

```
var hideTimer;

function showCart() {
    $("#mini-cart").fadeIn(1000);
    if (hideTimer) {
        window.clearTimeout(hideTimer);
        hideTimer = null;
    }
}

function hideCart() {
    hideTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#mini-cart").fadeOut(1000);
    }, 500);
}

$("#nav-cart,#mini-cart").hover(showCart, hideCart);
```

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't help. The problem is mousing over the mini-cart not the nav-cart

Comment: There must be some conflict, I tried the exact same code but it still disappears.

Comment: 1: But the fiddle works right?  
2: My code is meant to replace **all** both your `hover()` calls.
3: Can you reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm just gonna go ahead and say that you answered it for me. I'm using Weebly and it has a lot of attached proprietary php scripts generating code that can obscure what Im trying to make

Comment: Thank you. I hope you can figure it out.